# fabric js custom icon rotating point

Tags: javascript, canvas

in fabric js how can i customize the rotating point? i have 3 additional controls they are, delete, z-order, rotate. i want to change the rotating point with an rotate icon.

so far i follow the demo http://fabricjs.com/interaction-with-objects-outside-canvas/ it works good for delete and z-order controll, but for rotate it's stay on top of rotating point, therefore it's hard to rotate the object. here is the code on how do i do that.

```
canvas.on("object:selected", function(obj){
        jQuery(".deleteBtn").remove(); jQuery(".zOrderBtn").remove(); jQuery('.rotateBtn').remove();
        var btnLeft = obj.target.oCoords.mt.x - 40;
        var btnTop = obj.target.oCoords.mt.y - 50;
        var orderLeft = obj.target.oCoords.mt.x + 10;
        var orderTop = obj.target.oCoords.mt.y - 50;
        var rotateLeft = obj.target.oCoords.mt.x - 10;
        var rotateTop = obj.target.oCoords.mt.y - 50;
        var deleteBtn = '<img src="assets/images/delete-trash.png" class="deleteBtn" title="Delete" style="position:absolute;top:'+btnTop+'px;left:'+btnLeft+'px;cursor:pointer;" />';
        var zOrderBtn = '<img src="assets/images/zorder.png" class="zOrderBtn" title="Bring to top" style="position:absolute;top:'+orderTop+'px;left:'+orderLeft+'px;cursor:pointer;" />';
        var rotateBtn = '<img src="assets/images/rotate.png" class="rotateBtn" title="Rotate" style="position:absolute;top:'+rotateTop+'px;left:'+rotateLeft+'px;cursor:pointer;" />';
        jQuery("#canvas-wrap").append(deleteBtn);
        jQuery("#canvas-wrap").append(zOrderBtn);
        jQuery("#canvas-wrap").append(rotateBtn);
        currentDeleteBtn = jQuery('.deleteBtn').eq(0);
        currentOrderBtn = jQuery('.zOrderBtn').eq(0);
        currentRotateBtn = jQuery('.rotateBtn').eq(0);
    });
```

and here is screenshot of the canvas https://i.stack.imgur.com/lEXBq.png

Answer (score -1):

You can modify the default fabric functions to get that.

[This](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/fabricjs/7bzRM3RDa1I) may help you.
And [this](https://github.com/RohithKP/Canvas-App)
is a link to my git repo, there is a canvas app i made using fabric.